# Django form for multiple user settings

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have an application where each user can have several email id's.(Assume these emails are stored in a list)

Associated with each email, I have a fixed number of settings, which I can retrieve/save by a:
"user.email.settings.setting1 = 'value' "

I want the user to be able to change the settings for all the emails simultaneously and then submit all the changes, as shown in the following figure :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/h22cj.jpg

How can I achieve this in Django?

Should I have separate forms/views or can I implement this in a single go?

Comment: You can implement it as one form and one view, having all input values in your screenshot submitted each time, of course insuring that the previous values are preloaded into the form so you don't overwrite. In your view you can loop over the GET/POST variables and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: You should be able to get there in one form/view.  Have you used Django Formsets before?  If I'm understanding you correctly, they seems like they are a perfect fit.  Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/  If that's close, and you still need help, edit your question to include code of your models, or explain your db schema (assuming these email settings are stored in a db).

Comment: Thank you @BrianDant . The Django Formsets was a perfect fit.